# Conditions for birth and death process having only finitely many deaths.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a birth and death process on $\mathbb{N}=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots\right\}$, given by the transition probabilities $p(n,n+1)=\lambda_n$ and $p(n,n-1)=\mu_n$ (those are the birth and death rates, respectively), which satisfy $\lambda_n+\mu_n=1$. We assume $\lambda_n$ and $\mu_n$ to be strictly positive (so this process is irreducible).

I'm looking for conditions on the coefficients $\lambda_n$ (and $\mu_n$) that imply that, with probability $1$, almost every sample path in this system will have only births after a certain time.

More formally, let $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ denote the space of sample paths with the standard probability induces by the stochastic matrix $P=(p(n,m))_{n,m=0}^\infty$ (considering the initial distribution as the Dirac-distribution centered at $0$). I'm looking for conditions on the coefficients $\lambda_n$ and $\mu_n$ which imply that for a.e. sample path $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that $x_{N+k}=x_N+k$ for all $k\geq 0$ (that means that there are no deaths after time $N$).

Such a condition would probably be of the form "If $\mu_n$ decays [very fast], then almost every sample path has only finitely many deaths". This is actually equivalent to for almost every sample path $(x_n)_{n=0}^\infty$, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} (n-x_n)$ existing (note that $n-x_n$ is simply twice the number of deaths that ocurred between times $0$ and $n$).

---

This is what I have done so far: We can to calculate the probability of a sample path having only finitely many deaths. More precisely,

1. The probability of a sample path having only $1$ death is $\lambda_0\lambda_1\lambda_2\cdots=\prod_{j=1}^\infty \lambda_j$ (the only path is $(0,1,2,3,\ldots)$, and $\lambda_0=1$)
2. If a sample path has only one death at time $n$, then it is the path $(0,\ldots,n,n-1,n,n+1,n+2,\ldots)$, and the chance of it occuring is $\lambda_0\cdots\lambda_{n-1}\mu_n\lambda_{n-1}\lambda_n\lambda_{n+1}\cdots=\mu_n\lambda_{n-1}(\prod_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j)$. Thus, the probability of a sample path having precisely one death is $(\prod_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j)(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu_n\lambda_{n-1})$.

(The argument in the next paragraph is oversimplified, but I'm pretty sure that this is true. This becomes clearer if we calculate the probability of a sample path having 2 deaths, but the argument would be wuite long).

Note, from 2. above, that a death at time $n$ affects the probability by a term of the form $\mu_n\lambda_{n-1}$. If a sample path $(x_0=0,1=x_1,x_2,\ldots)$ has $k$ deaths at times $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k$, in that order, then after the time $n_i$, $x_{n_{i+1}}$ will be at least $x_{n_{i}}-1$. Hence the probability of a sample path having precisely $k$ deaths is
$$(\prod_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j)\sum\left\{\mu_{n_1}\lambda_{n_1-1}\cdots\mu_{n_k}\lambda_{n_k-1}:n_i\geq 1,\ n_{i+1}\geq n_i-1\right\}.$$

Therefore, the probability of a path having only finitely (including $0$) many deaths is
$$(\prod_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j)\left(1+\sum\left\{\mu_{n_1}\lambda_{n_1-1}\cdots\mu_{n_k}\lambda_{n_k-1}:k\geq 1,n_i\geq 1,\ n_{i+1}\geq n_i-1\right\}\right).$$
Thus, a.e. sample path has only finitely many deaths iff the ugly guy up here equals $1$. In particular $0<\prod_{j=1}^\infty\lambda_j=\prod_{j=1}^\infty(1-\mu_j)$, and if I remember correctly, this is equivalent to $\sum\mu_j<\infty$ (simply take $\log$'s, etc...).

I hope someone has a nicer condition for we almost always having only finitely many deaths.

Comment: Yes the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_n\mu_n$ is a necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: @Did Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: No, just the usual zero-one type argument.

Comment: @Did I don't really understand what you mean by "zero-one argument", I'm sorry. Could you please explain a bit more? Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Questioner: What Did means is that the event only births occur past a certain $N$ is in the tail-sigma algebra, which means by Kolmogorov's 0-1 theorem that it has probability 0 or 1. So if you want to show it has probability 1, it suffices to show that the probability is greater than 0 by some crude but hopefully simple argument.

Comment: @AlexR. Thank you. I was not aware of this result ([Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law#Formulation)). I can show that the event of having only finitely many deaths is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra. The problem is that the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{A}_j$ generated by the projections $\pi_j(x_n)=x_j$ are not independent (the probability considered in the path space is not the usual product measure). Do you know how to solve this? (you can write in an answer, if you want)

Answer (score 1):

An elementary argument we can make is as follows: Define by $d_n$ the expected number of deaths occurring before we reach state $n+1$ given that we start in state $n$. We clearly have $d_0=0$. Further we can write an expression for $d_n$ noting that, with, probability $\lambda_n$, we will have no deaths before reaching state $n+1$, and with probability $\mu_n$ we will have an additional death, regress to state $n-1$, expecting $d_{n-1}$ deaths before returning to state $n$ for $d_n$ more expected deaths before state $n+1$:
$$d_n=\mu_n(d_{n-1}+d_n+1)$$
$$d_n=\frac{\mu}{1-\mu}(d_{n-1}+1).$$
It is quite clear that the expected number of deaths, in general, is $D=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }d_n$, since we expect $d_0$ deaths before reaching state $1$, and $d_1$ additional deaths before reaching state $2$ and $d_2$ deaths before reaching state $3$ and so on. If $D$ is finite, the probability of a given sample having only finitely many deaths *must* be $1$, since if, with positive probability, infinite deaths might happen, $D$ would have to diverge.

Note that it is obvious that $\mu_n\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. We can use this crude, but clearly necessary condition to find a sufficient condition. In particular, choose some $N$ such that for all $n>N$ it holds that $\mu_n<\frac{1}3$. Then, we have that
$$d_n<\frac{1}2(d_{n-1}+1)$$
which, in particular, implies that, as the series of $d_n$ is converging exponentially towards $1$, that for large enough $N'>N$ it will hold that, for all $n>N'$ we have
$$0< d_{n-1}<2$$
which implies moreover that
$$\frac{\mu_n}{1-\mu_n}<d_n<\frac{3\mu_n}{1-\mu_n}$$
and since we have $0<\mu_n<\frac{1}3$ in this range, we can bound the ratios:
$$\mu_n < d_n < \frac{9}2\mu_n$$
which, being linear bounds means that $D=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}d_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\mu_n$  does. Since $D$ existing implies there being finitely many deaths in almost all cases, this means that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\mu_n$ converging to a finite value is a sufficient condition. (An argument that this is also necessary is also provided below)

---

Also, to flesh out the comments, because knowing about the [Kolmogorov zero-one law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law) is a plus, to solve this using that, notice that the event "there are only finitely many deaths" is a tail event since (over the space of unbounded paths; the set of bounded paths obviously has measure $0$, so we ignore it) it can be defined based on the series of independent events $X_n$ defined as "there is a transition $n$ to $n-1$ at some point" and changing finitely many $X_n$ does not change whether there were only finitely many deaths. The zero-one law states that this means that the probability of there being finitely many deaths is either $1$ or $0$.

We can note that the probability of there being only finitely many deaths is at least the probability of there being $0$ deaths, which is $$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} (1-\mu_n)$$
which is greater than $0$ if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mu_n$ converges. In that case, the probability of there being finitely many deaths is positive, and hence equals $1$, by the zero-one law. Conversely, suppose the probability of there being $0$ deaths is $0$ - meaning the sum of the $\mu_n$ diverges. This implies that the probability of there being $0$ deaths, starting at a population of $n$ is also $0$ - which in turn, implies that the probability of an additional death occurring eventually, regardless of the starting sequence, is $1$, so the probability of exactly $n$ deaths occurring is $0$ for any $n$ and, "finitely many" being a countable union of "none", "exactly one", "exactly two", $\ldots$, each having probability $0$, meaning there are almost always infinitely many deaths in this case.

Comment: "If D is finite, the probability of a given sample having only finitely many deaths must be 1" True. "D [finite] is equivalent to the statement that almost all samples will have only finitely many deaths." Not true a priori (some almost surely random variables have infinite expectation hence "almost all samples have only finitely many deaths" does not imply "D finite").

Comment: @Did Oops, thanks for catching that. Lacking any good method to prove that $D$ must have finite expectation if it is almost always finite (without first proving that $\sum \mu_n$ converging is necessary, which would obviate the proof), I edited the post so that it does not claim that the first bit proves that $\sum \mu_n$ must converge.